# "A2042 statement too complex" on a big BYTE array in MASM

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2015, x86, masm

I'm studying to pass param between .asm and .c in visual studio.

so I coded 'convert ascii to ebcidic'

.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern long convert(char);

void main()
{
    char val_1;
    int result;

    scanf("%c", &val_1);

    result = convert(val_1);
    printf("%x", result);
}
```

.asm

```
    .MODEL FLAT

    .DATA

    table BYTE 00h, 01h, 02h, 03h, 37h, 2Dh, 2Eh, 2Fh, 16h, 05h, 25h, 0Bh, 0Ch, 0Dh, 0Eh, 0Fh, 
                10h, 11h, 12h, 13h, 3Ch, 3Dh, 32h, 26h, 18h, 19h, 3Fh, 27h, 1Ch, 1Dh, 1Eh, 1Fh, 
                40h, 5Ah, 7Fh, 7Bh, 5Bh, 6Ch, 50h, 7Dh, 4Dh, 5Dh, 5Ch, 4Eh, 6Bh, 60h, 4Bh, 61h, 
                F0h, F1h, F2h, F3h, F4h, F5h, F6h, F7h, F8h, F9h, 7Ah, 5Eh, 4Ch, 7Eh, 6Eh, 6Fh, 
                7Ch, C1h, C2h, C3h, C4h, C5h, C6h, C7h, C8h, C9h, D1h, D2h, D3h, D4h, D5h, D6h, 
                D7h, D8h, D9h, E2h, E3h, E4h, E5h, E6h, E7h, E8h, E9h, ADh, E0h, BDh, 5Fh, 6Dh, 
                79h, 81h, 82h, 83h, 84h, 85h, 86h, 87h, 88h, 89h, 91h, 92h, 93h, 94h, 95h, 96h, 
                97h, 98h, 99h, A2h, A3h, A4h, A5h, A6h, A7h, A8h, A9h, C0h, 4Fh, D0h, A1h, 07h, 
                20h, 21h, 22h, 23h, 24h, 15h, 06h, 17h, 28h, 29h, 2Ah, 2Bh, 2Ch, 09h, 0Ah, 1Bh, 
                30h, 31h, 1Ah, 33h, 34h, 35h, 36h, 08h, 38h, 39h, 3Ah, 3Bh, 04h, 14h, 3Eh, E1h, 
                41h, 42h, 43h, 44h, 45h, 46h, 47h, 48h, 49h, 51h, 52h, 53h, 54h, 55h, 56h, 57h, 
                58h, 59h, 62h, 63h, 64h, 65h, 66h, 67h, 68h, 69h, 70h, 71h, 72h, 73h, 74h, 75h, 
                76h, 77h, 78h, 80h, 8Ah, 8Bh, 8Ch, 8Dh, 8Eh, 8Fh, 90h, 9Ah, 9Bh, 9Ch, 9Dh, 9Eh, 
                9Fh, A0h, AAh, ABh, ACh, 4Ah, AEh, AFh, B0h, B1h, B2h, B3h, B4h, B5h, B6h, B7h, 
                B8h, B9h, BAh, BBh, BCh, 6Ah, BEh, BFh, CAh, CBh, CCh, CDh, CEh, CFh, DAh, dBh, 
                DCh, DDh, DEh, DFh, EAh, EBh, ECh, EDh, EEh, EFh, FAh, FBh, FCh, FDh, FEh, FFh

    .CODE

    PUBLIC _convert
_convert PROC
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, [ebp+8]
    mov ebx, OFFSET table
    xlat
    pop ebp
    ret
_convert ENDP

    END
```

but it has errors "[A2006 undefined symbol : table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f36z3whz.aspx)" and "[A2042 statement too complex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/ca86c78h(v=vs.90).aspx)"

how can I fix it?

Comment: This would be a better question if you googled those error numbers and made them into links to the full description pages on Microsoft's site, so people that want to answer the question don't have to look them to check the docs themselves first.

Comment: Yup. I added the link.

Comment: I assume the "too complex" is on the line with the table, and maybe that's why it comes up as undefined.  Try using multiple separate `BYTE` directives instead of one giant one.  (In assembly language, bytes go where you put them.  It's not like C where the compiler can reorder your declarations).

Comment: or maybe `db` instead of `BYTE` will do. I don't know though.

Comment: XLAT is slower than just using `movzx eax, byte [ebp+8]` / `movzx eax, byte [table + eax]`.  No need to save/restore the caller's EBX (which your function fails to do).  If you decide to keep using XLAT, you should be saving/restoring EBX in this function.  It might not actually crash in your test case, but that's just luck.

Comment: Oh also, XLAT only modifies AL.  So your function returns with the upper 24 bits of EAX holding whatever high garbage the caller left on the stack above the 8-bit `char` arg.  (And your prototype says it returns `long`, not `char`, so callers will look at the full EAX.  Solution: declare your arg as `long`, or use `movzx eax, byte [ebp+8]` before XLAT.  (Or see my previous comment, which avoids that problem with only MOVZX.)  And yes, AFAIK the standard 32-bit Windows calling convention does allow callers to leave high garbage in narrow args.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I separated the table, but it has more errors like 'A2006 undefined symbol : A4h' (A0h~FFh)...

Comment: I solved this problem. solution is not XXh but 0XXh. :)